# Find element has className in enzyme not found with renderoption autocompleted material

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing react component use enzyme and jest test. I'm try use find method in enzyme but it not found, i'm sure this element have been render because when I print actionClass const it return value "ts-cbb-item".
I have a combobox component:

```
 /* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './index.scss';
import InputCombobox from './input-combobox';

const ComboBox = (props) => {

  const { 
    loading,
    options,
    onDataBinding,
    onChange,
    customRenderItem,
    placeholder,
    renderStartAdornment,
    closeIcon,
    disabled,
    customGetOptionLabel,
    onInputChange,
    style,
    clearOnBlur = false,
    defaultValue,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  const currentSearch = useRef();

  const [currentOption, setOption] = useState(null);

  const [isInput, setIsInput] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (_, value, reason) => {
    const isReasonInput = reason === 'input';
    
    if (isReasonInput) {
      setIsInput(false);

      if (onInputChange)
        onInputChange(value);  
    }

    currentSearch.current = value;

    if (value?.length < 3) return;

    if (isReasonInput) onDataBinding(value);
  }


  const handleChangeOpt = (opt) => {
    setIsInput(true);
    
    if (onChange) onChange(opt);
  }

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      clearOnBlur={clearOnBlur}
      disabled={disabled}
      closeIcon={closeIcon}
      className="ts-combobox"
      options={options}
      loading={loading}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => customGetOptionLabel 
          ? customGetOptionLabel(option) 
          : option.label}
      getOptionSelected={option => {
          if (!currentOption || !currentOption.value) return false;
          return option.value === currentOption.value;
        }}
      style={style ? style : { width: '100%' }}
      renderOption={(option, state) => {
        const actionClass = state?.selected ? "ts-ccb-item active" : "ts-ccb-item";
        console.log('class:', actionClass);
        return <div
                onClick={() => {
                    setOption(option);
                    handleChangeOpt(option);
                  }} 
                className={actionClass}>
                  { customRenderItem 
                    ? customRenderItem(option, currentSearch) 
                    : option.label }
        </div>
      }}
  );
}

export default ComboBox;
```

This is my test :

```
let initProps = {
        loading: false,
        options: [],
        onDataBinding: () => {},
        onChange: () => {},
        customRenderItem: () => {},
        renderStartAdornment: () => {},
        closeIcon: null,
        disabled: false,
        customGetOptionLabel: () => {},
        onInputChange: () => {},
        style: null,
        clearOnBlur: false,
        placeholder: '',
        defaultValue: null       
    }

    const options = [
        {
            label: 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
            value:  'Portugal'
        },
        {
            label : 'Leo Messi', 
            value :  'Argentina'
        },
        {
            label : 'Jesse Lingard',
            value : 'England'
        }
         
    ]

    const event = { 
        preventDefault() {},
    }
    
    const onInputChangeMockFn = jest.fn((value) => value);

    const onDataBindingMockFn = jest.fn( (value) =>  value? true: false);
    
    const renderStartAdornmentMockFn = jest.fn((option) =>  option ? option.value : null );

    const customGetOptionLabelMockFn = jest.fn((option) => option? option.label : null)

    const renderInputParams = {
        id: '',
        disabled: false,
        fullWidth: true,
        size: 'small',
        InputLabelProps: {},
        InputProps: {},
        inputProps: {}
    }




 it("Test_Comobox_With_RenderInput_Active(RenderStartAdornment_Have_Value)", () => {

        initProps.renderStartAdornment = renderStartAdornmentMockFn;
        
        initProps.customGetOptionLabel = customGetOptionLabelMockFn;

        initProps.options = options;

        const wrapper = mount(
                <ComboBox {...initProps} />
        );

        const autoCompleted = wrapper.find(Autocomplete);

        autoCompleted.props().renderOption(options[1], autoCompletedRenderOptionState);

        autoCompleted.props().renderInput(renderInputParams);

        expect(autoCompleted.find('div .ts-cbb-item')).toHaveLength(1);

        const inputCombobox = wrapper.find(InputCombobox);

        expect(inputCombobox.props().renderStartAdornment).toBeUndefined();

    })
```

How can I find exactly element div has ClassName 'ts-cbb-item' in this case?

Comment: Hi, this is my enzyme code: 

`const autoCompleted = wrapper.find(Autocomplete);

        autoCompleted.props().renderOption(options[1], autoCompletedRenderOptionState);

        autoCompleted.props().renderInput(renderInputParams);

        expect(autoCompleted.find('div .ts-cbb-item')).toHaveLength(1)`

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, thanks for reply, I was edited my post, can you reproducible for resolve this problem. Please let me know if you ant questions !